# Распределение задач RabbitMQ по алгоритму round-robin

Tags: php, rabbitmq

Доброго времени суток.

В проекте реализованы очереди на RabbitMQ с алгоритмом round-robin распределения задач по воркерам. Выявлена проблема - имеется три воркера, первый получил задачу - работает, второй, третий получили - быстро отработали. Первый воркер все еще занят, в очереди появилось еще одно задание и оно ждет освобождения первого воркера вместо того, чтобы передать следующему свободному.

Возможно исправить эту ситуацию, оставив алгоритм round-robin, чтобы свободные воркеры по очереди получали задачи? Спасибо.

Код создания задачи (PHP):

```
  $channel->queue_declare($queueName, false, false, false, false);

  $message = new AMQPMessage($task, [
      'delivery_mode' => AMQPMessage::DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT
  ]);

  $channel->basic_publish($message, '', $queueName);
```

Код подключения воркера:

```
$channel->queue_declare($queueName, false, false, false, false);

$channel->basic_consume(
        $queueName, '',
        false, true, false, false,
        $handler
);

while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
    $channel->wait();
}
```

Handler - метод

```
public function handler(AMQPMessage $message)
{
    $taskId = intval($message->body);
    if (!$task = Task::findOne($taskId)) {
        $this->log("Task id: {$taskId} not found.", 'warning');
        return;
    }

    $method = 'on' . ucfirst($task->command);
    $taskHandler = new TaskHandler;


    $this->log("Task with command '{$task->command}' handled.");

    $task->execute();

    if (method_exists($taskHandler, $method)) {
        $this->executeMethod($task, $taskHandler, $method);
    } else {
        $this->log("Command '{$method}' not found!", 'error');
    }
}
```

Реализация получения задачи через basic_get

```
   while (!$this->stopFlag) {

        if ($msg = $channel->basic_get($name, true)) {
            call_user_func_array($handler, [$msg]);
        }

        usleep(10 * 1000);

        pcntl_signal_dispatch();
    }
```

Comment: Посмотрите примеры на https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html, у вас отсутствует уведомление о том что работа завершена в воркере ($callback функция). Из-за этого не происходит, надеюсь, понимаете что. Приведите пример кода в $handler, думаю у вас там делается не то что нужно. Плюс надеюсь вы знаете что воркеры нужно запускать самостоятельно, RabbitMQ не будет их за вас запускать при получении сообщений, предназначенных им.

Comment: Конечно же я изучал туториал по rabbitmq на этом сайте. Воркеры запускаются отдельным процессом, в этом плане все ок. Callback я не использую, а также отключена функция подтверждения выполнения (no_ack = true в basic_consume), так как они не требуются по задаче.

Если я включу acknowledge механизм изменится? Код воркера я привел, остальные его части не могут иметь отношения к проблеме. Другого обращения к rabbitMq (кроме создания подключения) у них нет.

Comment: Добавил код функции $handler. Как видите, он ничего не возвращает. Может только кидать критические исключения.

Comment: Хороший вопрос на этом ресурсе! Держите его!

Answer (score 1):

Указанное поведение - это определение round-robin. Если его исправить, то есть отправлять задачи "по round-robin" но только в свободные worker'ы, то это будет уже не round-robin.

У вас включен no_ack - значит rabbitmq не знает закончил ли ваш worker обработку предыдущего отправленного ему сообщения. Он просто отправляет поступающие сообщения подключенным consumer'ам по round-robin. Это обычный и самый эффективный режим работы AMQP, но тут есть свои ньюансы, один из которых вы наблюдаете.

В качестве решения я бы предложил перейти на использование basic_get вместо basic_consume. Ещё есть [вариант](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) с включением ack'ов и настройкой basic_qos, но в данном случае по моему мнению он менее интуитивен и использование basic_get не так уж и сильно ухудшит производительность, хотя в случае с basic_qos поведение будет ближе к желаемому "round-robin по свободным worker'ам".

Comment: Теперь возникла проблема еще хуже - воркеры стали переодически хватать задание вместе. То есть выполняют одно и тоже :(

 Попробую решить через mutex

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить к каналу в консьюмере QOS

```
$channel->basic_qos(0, 0, false);
$channel->queue_declare($queueName, false, false, false, false);
```

Comment: К сожалению, эффекта не дало.

Comment: Хм, странно... у меня именно это решило эту проблему

Comment: Видимо потому, что я вручную ack-аю.